# In command-line mode, how to avoid delete key erasing last character?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line

On command-line mode, `Delete` key erases next character, but if cursor is at end of line, it acts as `Backspace`, erasing previous character. Can I disabled that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
:cnoremap <expr> <del> strlen(getcmdline()) == getcmdpos() - 1 ? '' : "\<del>"
```

This binds the delete key on the :-command line to running an expression and executing the keystrokes the expression returns.  In this case I'm using a ternary operator to return nothing if the length is the same as the cursor position, and returning the delete key otherwise.